# Server returning 404 when Vue-Cli project served over tomcat

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have started a project using vue-cli and after my development process is done, I am trying to deploy it to my local server Tomcat. But when I deploy it by running "npm run build" place the dist folder onto my webapps in tomcat and  and go to the app using my ip-address I am not able to hit the page. I am getting 404 error. Please help me if I am missing some configuration that needs to be done

Comment: Is there any error log?